ERROR: Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from
I am using Node and express along with svelte on the frontend, I have npm installed the "socket.io-client" package on the client side, but when I try to import it, I get this error.
I see this error only when importing "socket.io-client", I tried importing axios and it was working fine.
How to solve this issue?
This is how I am importing and this is the error that I get
I have tried everything, including clearing the cache, unistalling node modules and reinstalling them.
I tried using "require" as well, but It did not work.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
